# Как "найти" boost.program_options?

Tags: c++, cmake

В своем проекте на C++ применяю boost.program_options. В ручную настроенный проект из MSVS 2013 и 2017 отлично компилируется.

В данный момент настраиваю проект для компиляции на Windows 10. В переменную среды `BOOST_ROOT` указал значение `k:\projects\cpp-workspace\boost-libraries\`.

Вот как я компилировал Boost, пример для одной платформы и debug-конфигурации:

```
.\b2.exe --without-wave ^
    --without-python ^
    --without-graph_parallel ^
    --without-graph ^
    stage --stagedir=stage32 ^
    toolset=msvc ^
    variant=debug ^
    link=static ^
    threading=multi ^
    runtime-link=static
```

Появились папки:

- k:\projects\cpp-workspace\boost-libraries\stage32\lib\
- k:\projects\cpp-workspace\boost-libraries\stage64\lib\

В CMake-скрипте написал:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED program_options)
message(status "** Boost_INCLUDE_DIR: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(status "** ENV BOOST_LIBRARYDIR: $ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR}")
message(status "** Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
message(status "** Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
```

Получаю:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1902 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.60.0

  Boost include path: K:/projects/cpp-workspace/boost-libraries

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_program_options

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  readpe/CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)


status** Boost_INCLUDE_DIR: K:/projects/cpp-workspace/boost-libraries
status** ENV BOOST_LIBRARYDIR:
status** Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS:
status** Boost_LIBRARIES:
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "K:/projects/cpp-workspace/readpe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Этот Boost компонент комплируем, а не Header-Only вариант. Об этом говорит наличие файла `k:\projects\cpp-workspace\boost-libraries\stage32\lib\libboost_program_options-vc120-mt-s-1_60.lib`.

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы библиотеки нашлись? Неужели явным образом назначать в переменную `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` ?

Comment: FIND_PACKAGE( Boost 1.60 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED ) что-то дает?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646405/how-do-you-add-boost-libraries-in-cmakelists-txt

Comment: Я пробовал уже и видел эту и 3 подобные этой. Результат тот же!

Comment: stage32 это довольно странный путь, сколько не собирал boost это всегда было просто stage. Не смотрел я как CMake ищет boost, но можно попробовать переименовать stage32 в stage.

Comment: @ixSci только только на него подумал ;))) Поэтому и обновил свой вопрос

Comment: Там в коде модуля везде окончание вида `/stage/lib`. Попробуй выставь `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` в `Полный_путь/stage32/lib`

Comment: При выяснении, почему `find_package(Boost)` чего-то не находит, полезно включать опцию *Boost_DEBUG*, например передавая `cmake` опцию `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON`. С такой опцией будут показываться конкретные файлы, которые ищутся, и в каких директориях они ищутся.